# Шапка сайта прилипла к карточкам товара

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы карточка товара стояла внизу, а то она прилипла к шапке. Ставил margin-top, свойство ещё меняет шапку сайта.

[image: Сайт]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #000;
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 700vh;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#block-body {
  width: 1035px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  width: 1035px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.5);
}

<!--#22B14C-->#block-content {
  width: 1035px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
}

.logo a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
  color: #b2aeb2;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.use {
  color: white;
}

.web {
  color: #429595;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;
}

.logo p {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #22B14C;
}

.top-menu {
  width: 685px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.top-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 171px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "ProximaNova", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #121313;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top-menu ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #22B14C;
}

.block-top-auth {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 80px;
}

.block-top-auth p {
  margin-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.block-top-auth a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121313;
  font-family: "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block-top-auth a:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  color: #124f2e;
}

nav ul ul .submenu-link {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li .submenu-link {
  min-width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}


/* Стили меню */

.submenu-link {
  display: block;
  width: 171px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "ProximaNova", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #121313;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.submenu-link:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #22B14C;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

.submenu-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ProximaNova", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128);
  border-bottom-width: thin;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .submenu-content {
  display: block;
}


/*.dropdown:hover .submenu-link {background-color: #3e8e41;}*/

.fa {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.image {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-top: 10px;
}

.info h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.info-price {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.add-to-cart {
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.price {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>ВкусНяшка</title>
</head>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

<div id="block-body">

  <body>
    <header>

      <!--// разметка для логотипа -->

      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
          <!-- <span class="use">Вкус</span><span class="web">Няшка</span>-->
        </a>
        <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>
      </div>

      <!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

      <nav class="top-menu">
        <ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="submenu-link">Каталог<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
            <div class="submenu-content">
              <li><a href="#">ОВОЩИ, ФРУКТЫ, ЯГОДЫ, ЗЕЛЕНЬ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">fdddsf</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
            </div>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

      <div class="block-top-auth">
        <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="info">
            <h3>Название ава</h3>
            <div class="info-price">
              <span class="price">256<small>₸</small></span>
              <button class="add-to-cart"><ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="block-content"></div>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к header margin-bottom: 20px; и он отодвинет от себя любой блок на 20 пикселей в низ

Comment: Добавил margin-top:10px к фото, но кнопка покупки остался на месте(фото обновил сверху, посмотри), как это исправить?

Comment: @dqd015 по вашему body это фото?

Comment: Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: @dqd015 Прочитать что такое body и почему это не картинка. Начать с основ

Comment: Прочитал, значит мне надо body переместить вниз перед строкой div?